# Location on Jframe

Tags: java, swing, jframe, gridbaglayout

I am working on a [game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ludo_(board_game)) but have some issues with the location of the JLabels. I have this:

[image: http://puu.sh/k47m6/89136f7aeb.png]

as my board. I am trying to do two things:

1. Position "Ledu" on the top of the blue-ish board
2. Insert an randomly generated number under it so that it changes each time I press an image!

Here is my code:

```
start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        bp.removeAll();
        bp.revalidate();
        bp.repaint();
        BufferedImage mFrame2= null;

        try {
            mFrame2 = ImageIO.read(new File("B2.png"));
        } 
        catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        bp = new BackgroundPanel(mFrame2);
        bp.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        JLabel hi1 = new JLabel ("Ledu");
        Font fs = hi1.getFont();
        hi1.setFont(fs.deriveFont(30f));
        c.ipady = 0;       //reset to default
        c.ipadx = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.FIRST_LINE_END; 
        c.insets = new Insets(10,0,0,0);  //top padding
        bp.add(hi1, c);
        mainf.setContentPane(bp);
    };
});

mainf.pack();
mainf.setVisible(true);
```

How would I go about positioning the label on top of the blue box, and what would I need to do to have a random number generated, similar to a dice-roll?

Comment: Shall we suppose that the B2.png is the image you have attached with the coloured pieces?

Comment: B2 is the whole background, everything u see in the current picture ( apart of the word Ledo ) is a background, the image i will be inserting later which will generate a random number will be called dice.png

Comment: The label in the picture shows "Ledu". Point 1 refers to the text as "Ludo" and the comment above uses "Ledo". So are we talking about 3 different things or the same thing? Be consistent. Be accurate when describing a problem. We don't have time to read between the lines to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: i dont get you, there is one text "Ledo" which is shown in  the picture, i want to plug it in the top middle of the blue board. sorry if i was not clear enough

Comment: So why do you call the label "Ludo" and "Ledo" in your description of the problem. Are you talking about 3 labels.

Comment: miss-spelt it, i meant Ledu will fix it now and no we are talking about one label, Ledo it is

Comment: Neyon, I would suggest making the blue box an image of it's own, and have the board of the game it's own image. This separation would give you an easier time working with the Swing/Awt toolkits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1.Locate Ludo on the top of the blue-ish board

Well I don't know what that means. Does it mean in the absolute center of the blue area. Or does it mean top/left, top/center, top/right?

Be more descriptive so we don't have to guess.

Right now it looks to me like the label is in the center of the entire image. This is the default behaviour of a GridBagLayout. If you don't want the image in the center then you need to play with the weightx/weighty constraints.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for an explanation on how the constraints work.

However, I don't think this will solve your problem because you can't position components relative to the "blue" area of the larger image. I would suggest you need two images, one for the game board and one for the blue area. Then you can start to position components relatively on the blue area.

> 2.Insert an randomly generated number under it so that it changes each time I press an image!

Once you split the image as suggested above then you might use a vertical BoxLayout on the second image. Then you can display two labels, one with the text and the other with the number.

Comment: how could i do it code wise? i mean adding a blue area? and having the word Ludo in the top middle of it ? knowing that i want to locate the blue area in the same place

Comment: I explained how to do it. Create a JLabel with the blue image, set the layout manager, add the components.